# Function ToString doesn't return a value on all code paths

Tags: vb.net

I'm a student learning VB.NET.
I get "Function ToString doesn't return a value on all code paths"
on a overrides function?
and it does not work the way it should.
There is a combobox(Label11 references),  that selects the way the listbox layout is.
Here is the code that i have the problem with, any help will be appreciated.

```
Overrides Function ToString() As String

    Try
        If _label11 = "" Then
            Return _contactName & " - " & _SurName & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email
        Else
            If _label11 = "Name" Then
                Return _contactName & " - " & _SurName & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email
            Else
                If _label11 = "Surname" Then
                    Return _SurName & " - " & _contactName & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email
                Else
                    If _label11 = "Company Name" Then
                        Return "(" & _companyName & ")"  & vbTab & _contactName & " - " & _SurName & _state & vbTab & _email
                    Else
                        If _label11 = "Product" Then
                            Return _state & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _contactName & " - " & _SurName & _state & vbTab & _email

                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    Finally
    End Try
End Function
```

Here is what I have now,
It seems that the cmbSelect combobox does not send the info from my form2 to the contact class.
I have googled and tried everything to get it to work?
With the current one it gives an error"Object reference not set to an instance on an object"
Any idees?

```
Overrides Function ToString() As String
Select Case cmbSelect.SelectedIndex
        Case 0
               Return _contactName & " - " & _SurName '& vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email
        Case 1
            Return _contactName & " - " '& _SurName & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email
        Case 2                
            Return _SurName '& " - " & _contactName & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email
        Case 3                
            Return "(" & _companyName & ")" ' & vbTab & _contactName & " - " & _SurName & _state & vbTab & _email
        Case 4                
            Return _state & vbTab '& "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _contactName & " - " & _SurName & _state & vbTab & _email
        Case Else
            Return _contactName & " - " & _SurName & vbTab & "(" & _companyName & ")" & vbTab & _state & vbTab & _email & vbTab & _NumId
    End Select
End Function
```

Comment: What if  If __label11 <> "Product"_ ? I suggest to use a Select Case for better clarity of this code.

Comment: Also what if there is an exception? What do you return in this case?

Comment: As the error says, the function doesn't return a value on all code paths. The code paths that don't return a value are (1) when `If _label11 = "Product"` is false, and (2) when an exception is caught. You don't need the Try/Catch block, so I would get rid of it. Instead of all those indented `If` statements, use `Select Case`, and make sure you have a `Case Else` condition that returns an appropriate value when `_label11` is not one of the values you expect.

Comment: [Arrow Anti Pattern](https://blog.codinghorror.com/flattening-arrow-code/)

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I still cant get the Listbox to change the layout.